# Comparing function which satisfy certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x),g(x)$ are defined on $[-1,1]$ such that $f'(0),g'(0)$ exists, $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f(x)\ge g(x)$ for some open interval containing $0$.

Is this true?
 $\lim_ {x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} \ge \lim_ {x\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}$

I am making this assumption based on the fact that $f(0)=g(0)$ and the LHS with $f(x)$ in the numerator will always be greater.

Comment: In fact, under these conditions, you have $f'(0)= g'(0)$. If you had $f'(0) > g'(0)$, then, with $f(0) = g(0)$, it would follow that $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $-\varepsilon < x < 0$ and some $\varepsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) \geq g(x)$ in some neighborhood of $0$ and $f(0) = g(0)$, it is clear that you have $f(x) - f(0) \geq g(x) - g(0)$ for all $x$ in this neighborhood. Let $I$ be this neighborhood. You will have :

$$ \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} \geq \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x} $$

for all $x \in I \cap ]0,+\infty[$. Then,

$$ \lim\limits_{\substack{x \to 0 \\ x>0}} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} \geq \lim\limits_{\substack{x \to 0 \\ x>0}} \frac{g(x) - g(0)}{x} $$

is true.

Comment: and therefore $f'(x)\ge g'(x)$ is a valid conclusion.

Comment: No, 

$$ \lim\limits_{\substack{x \to 0 \\ x>0}} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = f'_{r}(0) $$

which is the right derivative of $f$ at $0$. So, the conclusion from my post would be : $f'_{r}(0) \geq g'_{r}(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

By the properties of limits, we have:

$ \lim_ {x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} \ge \lim_ {x\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}  \Leftrightarrow \ \lim_ {x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)-g(x)+g(0)}{x} \ge 0 \Leftrightarrow \ \lim_ {x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x} \ge 0 $

We know that $  \lim_ {x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x} $ exists, so $ \lim_ {x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x} = \lim_{\substack{x \to 0 \\ x>0}}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x} $

and we also know that

$ f(x) - g(x) \geq 0 $

for some open interval $ I $containing $ 0 $

therefore, $ \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x} \ge 0 $ for every $ x \in I\bigcap \mathbb{R}_{\geq0} $

Hence, $  \lim_{\substack{x \to 0 \\ x>0}}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x} \ge 0$